# The "OK" button is deactivated in creating new AVD although I have provided all details. So what is the problem?

Tags: android-emulator

The "OK" button is deactivated in creating new AVD although I have provided all details as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with user61926, you have the the CPU type for an Android Wearable but the display type is not set for an Android Wearbale.

Taken from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html)

> **2. Set Up the Android Wear Emulator**
>
> 1. Launch the Android Virtual Device Manager. 
>    1a. From Eclipse, select Window > Android Virtual Device Manager.  
>    1b. From Android
>      Studio, select Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
> 2. Click New.
> 3. For the AVD Name, enter "AndroidWearSquare" or "AndroidWearRound", depending on whether you want to create an emulator with a square or
>      round display.
> 4. For the Device, select Android Wear Square or Android Wear Round.
> 5. For the Target, select Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19 (or higher).
> 6. **For the CPU/ABI, select **Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a).** Note: Android Wear is designed to support multiple processor
>      architectures.**
> 7. **For the Skin, select AndroidWearSquare or AndroidWearRound.**
> 8. Leave all other options set to their defaults and click OK. 
>    Although real Android wearables do not provide a keyboard as an
>      input method, you should keep Hardware keyboard present selected so
>      you can provide text input on screens where users will instead provide
>      voice input.
> 9. In the list of AVDs, select the one you just created and click Start. In the following window, click Launch.
>
> The Android Wear emulator now starts. To begin testing your app's
>   notifications, you must now pair the emulator to your development
>   device that has the Android Wear Preview app installed.
>
> Tip: To improve the emulator startup time, edit your AVD and enable
>   Snapshot under Emulator Options. When you start the emulator, select
>   Save to snapshot then click Launch. Once the emulator is running,
>   close it to save a snapshot of the system. Start the AVD again, but
>   select Launch from snapshot and deselect Save to snapshot.
>
> Caution: Do not install apps on the Android Wear emulator. The system
>   does not support traditional Android apps and the result of running
>   such apps is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

It is something to do with the CPU type you have chosen (Android Wear) and the Skin? Do Android wearables really support up to HVGA screens?

Answer (score 0):

The AVD Name cannot contain spaces. Heaven knows why the programmers didn't raise an error in this case (or simply highlight the field and provide an explanation).